# Ordering elements with jQuery without ids

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am kinda stuck with re ordering issue with jQuery. In the followng code structre is like input>label>div but I need to put div first, then label and input in the lastest element.

As you can see label elements does not have id 's...so I am kinda stuck here:(
Any help?

```
<div class="taxonomy" id="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency">
<ul class="taxonomy_radiobuttons">
                    <li class="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_Notsmoking">
    <input type="radio" value="//wwx/6000 Context/Daily smoking frequency.model#NotSmoking" name="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency" id="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_Notsmoking">
    <label for="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_Notsmoking">.Not smoking</label>
            <div class="visual"><p><img src="/myapp/resources/dynamic/7139b8eb"></p></div>
                            </li>
                    <li class="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_0005">
    <input type="radio" value="//wwx/6000 Context/Daily smoking frequency.model#HalfPacket" name="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency" id="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_0005">
    <label for="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_0005">0,0-0,5</label>
            <div class="visual"><p><img src="/myapp/resources/dynamic/49b8660"></p></div>
                            </li>
                    <li class="wwx5000InstrumentsPriceandconditions.model#PriceAndConditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_0510">
    <input type="radio" value="//wwx/6000 Context/Daily smoking frequency.model#OnePacket" name="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency" id="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_0510">
    <label for="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_0510">0,5-1,0</label>
            <div class="visual"><p><img src="/myapp/resources/dynamic/7e930afc"></p></div>
                            </li>
                    <li class="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_1015">
    <input type="radio" value="//wwx/6000 Context/Daily smoking frequency.model#OneAndHalfPacket" name="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency" id="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_1015">
    <label for="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_1015">1,0-1,5</label>
            <div class="visual"><p><img src="/myapp/resources/dynamic/67b6674f"></p></div>
                            </li>
                    <li class="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_1520">
    <input type="radio" value="//wwx/6000 Context/Daily smoking frequency.model#TwoPacket" name="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency" id="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_1520">
    <label for="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_1520">1,5-2,0</label>
            <div class="visual"><p><img src="/myapp/resources/dynamic/7838a8ba"></p></div>
                            </li>
                    <li class="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_20">
    <input type="radio" value="//wwx/6000 Context/Daily smoking frequency.model#MoreThanTwoPacket" name="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency" id="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_20">
    <label for="wwx5000Instrumentsconditions.model#Conditions.classifies__InputObjectType_0_DailySmokingFrequency_20">&gt;2,0</label>
            <div class="visual"><p><img src="/myapp/resources/dynamic/4fcd88ff"></p></div>
                            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own suggestion:

```
$('.taxonomy_radiobuttons li').each(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        d = self.find('div'),
        i = self.find('input'),
        l = self.find('label');
    d.prependTo(self);
    l.appendTo(self);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vR3xa/).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this way:

```
$('.taxonomy ul li > input').before(function(){
   return $(this).siblings('.visual');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkydC/)**

[before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) takes a function argument to return the element to be inserted before the selected element, in the function return the div that is a sibling of the selected input.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) Try: http://jsfiddle.net/bCvbu/

```
$('li').each(function() {
    $div = $(this).find('div');
    $label = $(this).find('label');
    $input = $(this).find('input');
    $(this).html('');
    $(this).append($div, $label, $input);
});
```

Comment: Nope :( The code above is created dynamically. When I try to run it all the elements in the screen turns like this. I think I wil need to target a spesific ul to run this function:(              [object Object][object Object][object Object]
[object Object][object Object][object Object]
[object Object][object Object][object Object]
[object Object][object Object][object Object]

Comment: Thank you guys! Cant tell you how helpful was this for me. p.s. always thought that selectors (like ids etc) needed to function in jquery:D cheers.